# Validation of StringTemplate Templates

Tags: java, validation, templates, stringtemplate

I am using StringTemplate v4 and need to validate user generated templates. Since I am new to StringTemplate I was wondering if there is an easy way to validate templates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When searching [google](http://www.google.de/search?q=Validation%20of%20StringTemplate%20Templates) with your title, one of the first hits hints at [Template validation](http://www.antlr.org/pipermail/stringtemplate-interest/2009-April/001878.html) and at [StringTemplateErrorListener](http://www.stringtemplate.org/api3/org/antlr/stringtemplate/StringTemplateErrorListener.html). Maybe, this is what you're searching for.

I don't know, wether it's an easy way, since I have never used it.